# filter json results into image path

Tags: android, json, app-inventor, kodi

Hello i am using MIT App Inventor 2 to make an app that runs on an old (spare) android phone to display the folder.jpg of currently playing movie (later on I also want to do that with music).

I can't filter the path to use, for example this is the result of the json:

```
{"id":"VideoGetItem","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"item":{"id":1,"label":"2012","thumbnail":"image://F%3a%5cMovies%5c2012%5cfolder.jpg/","type":"movie"}}}
```

I want to keep: `image://F%3a%5cMovies%5c2012%5cfolder.jpg`  which is the dvd cover (and maybe the label:  `2012`  which is the title of the movie).

I tried various options like making a list but then I still get text with lot of params between '()'
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **JSON decode** block together with the **lookup in pairs** block. As you can see, it helps to use Do it...

[image]

Comment: i wil try that, let you know of progress.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that is doing it for me for starters.

I see a flaw but that's in Kodi(.tv) itself (I am not a fan of the library system in kodi, so I put a folder.jpg in every drawer of a movie, but sometimes kodi doesn't display it and presents me with a video preview of the movie, I have to sort that out with kodi developers)

For now I am glad I have it working,

[solution picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTApa.png)
[image]