# Display programmatically a ListView selected item in a label with App Inventor 2

Tags: json, listview, label, app-inventor, programmatically-created

I have managed to parse a [JSON result from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474521/filter-url-json-results-using-app-inventor-2) to a ListView. I need now to have the ListView searched for a specific element programmatically - without user picking form the list -  by a user input search.
Then if this element, according to user input is found in ListView, the result to be displayed in an label or a notification to be fired.

Can this be done using the ListView component in App Inventor 2?
Please advice, with a sample block code if applicable. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: search the list you created from the JSON response instead... as you already know from [my answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34500551/1545993), there is the *lookup in pairs* block waiting for you... Btw. it does not look like that answer was helpful for you, was it?

Comment: Hello @Taifun. Your answer was helpful, but could not implemented right, or the JSON was not formated in the right way for parsing maybe. There for, I followed a tutorial to parsing JSON in ListView, with a relative success. So there is no way to have the ListView searched for an element and displayed programmatically on a label?

Comment: I just was asking, because it looks like you do not know [how voting works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)... and No, you can't search a listview programmatically, you have to search the underlying list instead.