# Proper way of using ResultNotifier.ShowProgressDialog in App Inventor 2?

Tags: android, json, progressdialog, app-inventor, tinydb

Expanding the functionality of an under development app, I need to show to the user a progress notification dialog. Problem is, I cannot get it done right. Furthermore, I cannot dismiss this notifier properly. Have tried with a clock and a variable set to e.g. "5000ms" and then to "0", without any lack.

What I need to achieve is the following functionality:

a. Check if the tag "storeparsedData" is in a TinyDB, populated with the fetched JSON data. I have this done, following @Taifun advice in my [relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709320/how-to-check-if-a-tinydb-tag-has-any-attributes-in-app-inventor).

b. If the tag is not there (empty list), do a getWeb.gotText block to get the JSON data (this is done with procedure "getWebData". This functions right, but takes a while about 1'35'' or more, so need to show something to the user.

c. While fetching JSON data form web, need to show a "ShowProgressDialog" notifier to the user, so I can cope with the smartphone being seemingly freeze.

d. If the tag "storeparseData" is populated with fetched JSON data, dismiss the notifier.

Have tried the following coding, without relevant success:

[image]

Can someone help me out, to achieve this functionality in this app? A blocks code or something to follow and learn, will be awesome.
Thank you all in advance for your answers.

[Edit1]

After @Taifun suggestions, the functionality in question seems to be working, but there is a problem."ShowProgressDialog" block never fires, neither on device or companion. Also where should block "DismissProgressDialog" be attached to disable notifier upon JSON data received?

Here is the reviewed blocks code, for checking stored tags in TinyDB. "ShowProgressDialog" never fires as it should. Are there any suggestion for this issue?

[image]

Here is the blocks code for the getWeb function to get the JSON data:

[image]

Please advise, with a block code if applicable.Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `progressNotifier.AfterChoosing` event never will fire, because that event only fires after choosing something from a `Notifier.ShowChooseDialog` block, but not for `Notifier.ShowMessageDialog` blocks. Therefore use a `Notifier.ShowChooseDialog` block instead and set the second button in that block to empty string.

[image]

2. Your `while` loop will freeeze your app, as you already realized... **You do not need the `Clock.Timer` event at all** to check if your data is there.

Just do it like this: after having received your data in the `Web.GotText` event and having stored the data in `TinyDB`, then dismiss the progress dialog and display the message "Database is ready".

[image]

**Update**: Instead of storing your list n times inside the `for each in list` loop, you should store it only once after the `for each in list` loop is finished... Same for the `DismissProgressDialog` and `ShowAlert` block...

[image]

What is the purpose of that join block? You might want to remove it...

Comment: Hello Taifun. I was near to nail it, but your suggestion did the trick for that function, but there is a problem with the "ShowProgressDialog" as it does not fires. See my edit, if you are likely to help more.

Comment: Hello again Taifun. Yes there was an infinite loop at the list item function and I was getting the app running slow. Your suggestion with the "DismissProgressDialog" was also taken into account. I'll report back any other issues. As for now, your answer is the right answer to my question.